# How to calculate the driving distance between two points?

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, driving-distance

In my app I am getting the `latitude` , `longitude` co-ordinates of places using `GeocodeService` now I want to get distance between these places.

I've tried `GetDistanceTo` method to get the distance two location co-ordinates but it gives me stright distance.

How can I calculate **driving distance** between two locations?

thanks in advance

Comment: this might help you http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the driving distance you'll have to use the Bing Routes API (or Google, but I assume you're using Bing Maps).

There's an example of using the api to find a driving route between two places here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg636957.aspx

The general call is:
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?o=xml&wp.0=location1&wp.1=location2&avoid=minimizeTolls&key=BingMapsKey

You'll have to register for a Bing Maps API key, and then replace location1 and location2 with the locations you like.

The distance should be returned in `travelDistance` in the json or xml

Comment: yes am using bing maps i need only `traveldistance` i dont want route bitween places :)

Comment: The rest of the route info comes with the call, but you can ignore that, and just extract the travelDistance field :)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to exclude all the other and get only the distance?