# How to calculate distance between two zip code from bing map service

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I want to calculate distance between two zip code by bing map API. Is there any possible way to do this [I tried  this link but this is not for two zip code](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/geocoding-in-sql-server-with-the-bing-maps-locations-api/). Is there any way to do this.

I Pass ZIP1- 34481 and ZIP2- 34705 and want result 70.9 in miles
i calculate this direct from [bing map](https://www.bing.com/mapspreview?FORM=Z9LH3&mkt=en-in). Thanks for your response

Comment: Unless you have access to some sort of map coordinates for the zip codes, then I do not think it is possible.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen if you want to say lat, long  for two zip code then i have in my table

Comment: If you have latitude and longitude you can calculate the distances based on that

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen its calc air distance but i want road distance

Comment: Then you need to do as said in the answer and use the Routes API

Answer (score 0):

From reading the article, the example as stands will give you a `GEOGRAPHY` point object (although not sure if your inputs are valid, it seems it require a street address). Anyway, call it twice then to determine the distance between the points returned use something like

```
Point1.STDistance(Point2)
```

Here's the BOL reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx

Alternatively, see this question for a Bing Routes API answer. [How to calculate the driving distance between two points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831801/how-to-calculate-the-driving-distance-between-two-points)

If you still need to geocode the approx centre of a zipcode, you might be better off importing the data yourself. I did this recently for the Australian GNAF data (https://www.rednotebluenote.com/2016/04/importing-psma-geocoded-national-address-file-g-naf-to-sql-server/ ) which you might find useful background reading. For US I believe http://census.gov/ makes something similar available.

Hope this is of use.

Comment: i have lat and long for the zip 1 and zip 2 and want driving distance what what will the api i need to call

Comment: See the How to Calculate Driving Distance link.

Comment: i m using Route API of bing my request is for service is `http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?wp.0=0.5871776,-1.472574&wp.1=0.5742378,-1.490571&avoid=minimizeTolls&distanceUnit=mi&o=xml&key=mykey` but i m getting `<StatusCode>404</StatusCode>` what i m doing mistake in this request